# Display a pop up message inside a popup message

Tags: javascript

I’m developing a JavaScript code. When I click on the “Click me” button, a pop-up message will display with a message and “ok” button. When I click on the “ok” button on the pop-up message, it will close.
Now I want to do is when I click on the “ok” button on the pop-up window, it should close and I want to display another pop-up window with another button. If I click on that button, the second pop-up message should also be closed.
This is my code up to now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

div#overlay {
display: none;
z-index: 2;
background: #000;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

div#specialBox {
display: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
width: 500px; 
height: 300px;
background: #FFF;
color: #000;
}

div#wrapper {
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding-left:24px;
}

</style>

<script>



function toggleOverlay(){
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
overlay.style.opacity = .4;
if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
}
}

</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="overlay"></div>



<div id="specialBox">



 <p><center>Great job<center></p> 



<center><button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Ok</button><center>

</div>


<div id="wrapper">

 <p><center>Please click the button<center></p> 



<button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Click me</button>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jswk8uva/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just create another `specialBox`, say `specialBoxTwo` and you can have a function to toggle that item. `toggleOverlayTwo()`. Your first button would call both toggles (the first one to close the first overlay, second one to open the second overlay):

```
<button onmousedown="toggleOverlay();toggleOverlayTwo()">Ok</button>
```

And the second overlay only needs to toggle the second item:

```
<button onmousedown="toggleOverlayTwo()">Ok</button>
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qz3wjstw/). *Note* this is rather a "quick and dirty" example. You can clean this up but having perhaps a single toggle functions that takes a parameter and use classes for each speicalBox.

[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qz3wjstw/1/) with only using a single `toggleOverlay(item)` function that takes a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Spencer, It's working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aishy No problem, note make sure to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark to the left.